# andLess .flac "Decoder Error"

Tags: music-player, htc-sensation

I try to play a .flac audio file on my htc sensation with the [andLess player](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.avs234), but every time I try to open a file it just shows a "Decoder Error" with no further explanation. The .flac files work fine on my Creative Zen X-FI 2, so the files should not be the problem. I use android version 2.3.4.
Does anybody know this issue and/or have a solution for this?

**Update:**

Is it possible that I have to install the necessary codec on my own? From the description of the app, I assumed that it is delivered with the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest reporting the issue on the [andLess issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/andless/issues/list). I didn't see anything that relates to exactly what you mention but the developers may know what your issue is or they can correct it.

Comment: I want to make sure that I did not forgot to install anything or made any other fault before I bother the developer with this issue.

Comment: from what i have read, there is a liblossless.so that looks to handle the decoding, but it is distributed by the application.

Comment: Since the .flac files were ripped with custom settings, I will perform some tests with other files. (Like I said, the files work fine on other platforms) If that does not solve the problem, I will report the issue and accept your answer.

Comment: My files seem to be normal 16 bit 44,1khz .flac audio files. Therefore I will report this problem, thank you for answering.